# block hacked indexed pages of my Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Last month my WordPress site was hacked because of my theme, so many pages (300k ..) were indexed by Google.

The actual PHP files were removed and a WAF installed, but, here is my problem.

The indexed links are like this : `https://example.com/?bkzlriry235916cdefgh`, always the same pattern (random chars and numbers).

To get them removed from Google, I think a rewrite rule in Apache vHost or `.htaccess` can do the job to get a 404 or 410 HTTP Code.

Problem is that I can't match the question mark `?` using regex, even if I escape it. So the rule is wrong and blocks all my site.

I did something like that and many other tests :

```
RewriteRule ^/\?(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [NC]
```

Do you have an advice for me?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/\?(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [NC]
> ```

There are several things wrong here:

1. The `RewriteRule` directive matches the URL-path only, not the query string (everything after the `?`). You need a separate *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) and match against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable.
2. The URL-path that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against does not start with a slash.
3. This rule (if it did match) would trigger a 302 (temporary) redirect to the homepage and preserve the query string, resulting a redirect loop. As you stated, you need to issue a "410 Gone" to get these pages removed from Google.

Try the following instead at the top of the root `.htaccess` file. Importantly, this must go *before* the WordPress code block.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^\w+$
RewriteRule ^$ - [G]
```

This blocks (with a 410 Gone) any request to the homepage only (as per your example) that includes a query string consisting only of letters and numbers (ie. no actual URL parameter name=value pair).

If you are not expecting any query string on any URL then you can make it more generic:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^ - [G]
```